# Fields clash in case of inheritance

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I' ve the following simplified model structure:

```
#common/models.py
class CLDate(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

#br/models.py
class Dokument(CLDate):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Entity(CLDate):
    dokument = models.ForeignKey(Dokument)
```

. Both class inherits from CLDate, and i' ve a OneToMany relation between them. When i try to migrate, i got the following error:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
br.Entity.dokument: (models.E006) The field 'dokument' clashes with the 
field 'dokument' from model 'common.cldate'.
```

I can' t really get why is this structure a problem for Django hence the Entity is a totally different object than the Dokument. Could anyone explain me why, and how could i solve it with this structure? So both should inherit from CLDate and there should be this kind of relation between the 2 models from the br application.

I also tried to delete all the migration files, and solve it that way, but the same. Runserver gives also this error.

Django: 1.11.2
Python: 3.4.2
Debian: 8.8

.

Thanks.

---

If i rename the dokument property name in the Entity model, it works fine.

I' m also almost pretty the same layout was working previously (in previous Django versions).

Comment: Yes, i just updated the ticket, that that' d work, but i' d like to know the reason for this (and of course a cleaner solution would be not to change the naming convention).

Comment: Can that be overridden? So it uses a different name for its internal part?

Comment: Can you post your migrations, i suspect that you have had `document` field in `CLDate` previously.

Comment: I don' t think i had, however for test i deleted all the migrations and db... .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using multi-table inheritance, Django creates an implicit one-to-one field from `Dokument` to `CLDate`. The reverse relation `dokument` from `CLDate` to `Dokument` is clashing with your `Entity.dokument` field.

If you don't want to rename your `Entity.dokument` field, then your other option is to [explicitly define the parent link field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#specifying-the-parent-link-field) from `Dokument` to `CLDate` and set `related_name`.

```
class Dokument(CLDate):
    cl_date = models.OneToOneField(CLDate, parent_link=True, related_name='related_dokument')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: I should have thought for it, i use it many places... . Thanks.