# Overriding the save method of multiple Django models without making the change in each individual model

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-admin

I have a django project set up in which I have 6 (and will possibly add more in the future) models. I need the admin interface setup such that whenever I update or add an object to any of the models, it writes data to a file from the LogEntry class. I have chosen this method because post save signals will run on server start-up (I have dockerized this app and am importing tables into the postgres database from pre-existing csv files) and they throw errors. In order to achieve the functionality desired, I put the following in my models.py file.

```
class ModdedModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        changes_file = ("new_changes.txt","w")
        content2 = LogEntry.objects.all()
        changes_file.write(content2)
        super(ModdedModel, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

I then inherited this model for all subsequent tables that I want to create using the Django ORM. However this error appears,

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
mdp.Variants.variants: (models.E006) The field 'variants' clashes with the field 'variants' from model 'mdp.moddedmodel'.
```

I assumed maybe there was some namespace error and changed the field name to variants**s** to check if it would make a difference but I then got this instead

```
Did you rename variants.variants to variants.variantss (a CharField)? [y/N] y
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'moddedmodel_ptr' to enrichment without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

I don't know what is causing this ptr field to be added when I do this. I guess I could just add the save method to each individual class but there must be a cleaner method of doing this. It has nothing to do with my save method (I'm sure that would have been obvious from the errors anyway) because I've tried it for one class and it works fine. For reference if need be this is my overridden save method,

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    super(Enrichment, self).save(*args,**kwargs)    
    changes_file = open("new_changes.txt","w+")
    changes = LogEntry.objects.all()
    #print(changes)
    for change_made in changes:
        #print(change_made, changes)
        changes_file.write(str(change_made))
    changes_file.seek(0)
    #print(changes_file.read())
```

Comment: Does your `ModdedModel` have a field called `variants`? When inheriting from a model; your sub-class/model will inherit the super's fields, so having the same field in the super- and sub-class will lead to clashes.

Comment: The only thing in my ModdedModel is the save method. Nothing else. And like I said I did attempt to change the field name in the inherited model which would have solved the error in that case.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776488/fields-clash-in-case-of-inheritance) issue is the same as the one you're experiencing, but it's hard to tell without seeing your models. If the issue above doesn't help - could you post those? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, this is a great question link. I think one of my model names is clashing with one of the fields with the variants model because my Variants model does have a variants parameter in it. Brilliant, thanks for this. I'll edit my code and post results in a bit.

Comment: I still however, have no idea why the second error pops up after I change the parameter name. Because in the question you linked doing that solved the problem whereas in my case it seems to want to add a new field to my model. As I understand it is just a pointer variable showing the relation between classes but I am unsure how to set a default value for this field because I haven't explicitly created it and I also don't want to override it by writing the variable name in my code and specifying the default in case django has some format for the variable that it recognises.